# Why I was suspended for review queues?

Tags: support, review-suspension

Yesterday, I see that Review Queue is empty for me. So I have already suspended 1 time and I know that when queue is empty it is perhaps because I was suspended.

If found the review ban message on https://stackoverflow.com/review/, where it says:

> Your review on first-posts/26414818 wasn't helpful. Please review the
> history of the post and consider which action would achieve that
> outcome more quickly.
>
> Come back on Aug 18 at 17:23 to continue reviewing.

The reviewed question can been seen at https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26414818

I voted down, as did other 5 users and I left a comment that is following

> I vote down for lazy author. Please, don't use an image to describe
> your problem ! Take some time to write all these data in your
> question. Why ? To help other to help you ? That is only RESPECT
> others.

It seems strange that this review alone would lead to a suspension. I'm not sure what I should learn from this. How can I improve to avoid future review suspensions?

Why I was suspended?

1. because I vote down?
2. because I say that I vote down ?
3. because I say that user is lazy?
4. because I don't flag this question as closable?
5. because I consider that posting an image for code is incorrect?
6. because 3 other users have voted for my comment
7. because a moderator as decided to punish me
8. because I'm suspended for another reason

Why I'm suspended for **more** than 2 months?

Comment: Why didn't you flag for closure? Doing that is much more helpful than simply leaving a somewhat rude comment. If  one is going to comment in the review queues, one should try to be helpful. Particularly in the first-posts queue. And flagging/voting to close is very important. By not doing so while on review, you are effectively saying that the question  should remain open. The question will only have a few opportunities to be reviewed, and then it will be pushed out of the queue. So those opportunities should be used wisely.

Comment: You are jumping to conclusions to say "lazy" & "disrespectful".

Comment: The comment is definitely not nice because you comment on the user, not on the post. I would even consider it as rude. Why not just write "Please, don't use an image to describe your problem! Transcribe the content of your image into the question to help others to help you.". Same message but without the personal attacks.

Comment: @yivi. Thanks for this information. But why I have been suspended for more than 2 months (not only 2 months) and without explanation ?

Comment: There was an explanation, schlebe. Your review actions were not helpful. For an extended and detailed explanation, including why the suspension was this long, please refer to the answer below provided by Cody.

Comment: @BDL: but what is more abusive 'Saying to a new user that he is lazy' or 'suspending a reviewer for more than to 2 month without giving any reason'. I have courage to sign what I say, but what about moderator's courage ?

Comment: @schlebe Relax, notice the last point of Cody's answer. If you understand and accept what went wrong there, he might ease your ban.

Comment: It's more abusive calling a user names, no doubt about it. Suspending a user from review is not abusive, it's just using the site features to make the user aware of how to better review in the future. Do not be overly focused in the comment though, that was not the reason you were review-suspended. Please, read Cody's answer carefully and you'll see there is an opportunity for you to learn from this episode and get the suspension lifted early.

Comment: It actually takes more clicks to upload an image, than to copy'n'paste code, so "lazy" is not the right word. In general it's best to not make assumption about other users, because: 1. In most cases, you don't know about their personal struggle. 2: It's not constructive communication. If the post lacks something, then that's it: The **post** lacks something. What motivated the user to make a post lacking is not important.

Comment: @Scratte *"It actually takes more clicks to upload an image, than to copy'n'paste code"* - Welll..... it doesn't really take any clicks at all, just take a screen clip (win+shift+S, or alt+printscrn will do) and paste it in the answer box, then press enter to hit the "Add Picture" button, so we're talking 0 "clicks" here :p

Comment: @Nick Sorry :) On my system it's shift-windowsKey-S. Then clickCorner-hold-moveMouse-ReleaseMouseOnEndCorner (one click) :) But that's probably because I do not want it to make a full screen.

Answer (score 12):

You were suspended by a moderator because your action in the review queue did not help to resolve the problem(s) with the post. As the message says:

> Your review on https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26414818 wasn't helpful. Please review the history of the post and consider which action would achieve that outcome more quickly.

I don't think you can see the post (since it has now been deleted by its original author), but it was closed by the community for want of details or clarity.

You correctly identified the post as being problematic, but instead of flagging it as being in need of closure, you left a comment. Comments don't help to resolve the problem and are never sufficient.

You can downvote as you see fit, but this should not be used *instead* of a flag in cases where the post needs to be closed and/or deleted.

So, basically, you were suspended because of reason #3:

> 3. because I don't flag this question as closable

The result of that review should have been getting the question closed. Your review did not help to accomplish that task. Thus, it was not correct. We are advising you to re-consider your choice and hopefully make a better one next time you review.

Regarding the comment: yes, it was poorly phrased, and probably shouldn't have been left at all. There's never a reason to disclose in a comment how you voted (votes are anonymous), and doing so just creates unnecessary hostility. Furthermore, it's almost always best to let your close votes/flags speak for you. Only leave a comment if you have some additional feedback to provide that is unique to that specific post and directly actionable by the original poster. But the comment was not directly related to your review suspension.

> Why I'm suspended for more than 2 months?

Because the last time you were suspended from review, back on April 5, it was for 32 days. (You chose "Requires Editing" a couple of times in Triage for posts that couldn't possibly be edited into shape by the community. For these types of posts, you need to choose "Unsalvageable".) Since review suspensions double each time, you were suspended for 64 days this time.

About durations in general: moderators use review suspensions as teaching tools, notifying you that you made the wrong decision and hoping that you'll use this information to improve your reviewing skills in the future. But, due to limitations in the site's UI, these messages aren't as visible to users as we'd like them to be. Thus, we tend to use longer durations than punitive goals would seem to merit. If you express understanding and contrition, a moderator is generally willing to lift your suspension early.

Comment: thanks for this answer. I regret that moderator doesn't explain immediately why I was suspended forcing me to post this question on Meta. I have however some doubt about your reason's explanation because it is impossible for me than a moderator suspend me from ReviewQueue for this reason. I can accept that a moderator suspends me for 2 months because I have written than user is lazy but not because I don't have flagged a question as closable. A software can do that automatically, but a moderator doesn't waste his time on such thing.

Comment: @schlebe Complaining about not receiving enough immediate feedback while at the same time dismissing the detailed feedback you got seems like an intriguing strategy.

Comment: ["all posts reviewed will remain visible to their reviewers in the context of the relevant review task..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266868/165773) - ie, even deleted question will stay visible to any rep user at the link to review they made

Comment: @yivi: I disagree with you. My reasoning is correct. If moderator posted a comment with some explanations, I don't need to post this question and we don't have this conversation. I thank Cody Gray and others for their help. You don't see that (I think), but I voted for all of your comments !

Comment: @gnat: all post will remain visible is partially true ! Timeline has been deleted and is not more visible ! It is impossible to see if I have flagged the question or nor and for which reason.

Comment: *...but not because I don't have flagged a question as closable. A software can do that automatically...* If we had software to close questions, we wouldn't need the review queues at all. Most moderation is done by the community

Comment: @gnat Yeah, I know that they can still see the review, and therefore the contents of the question at the time. What I was unsure of is whether they can see what happens to it *afterwards*, including that it was voted to be deleted. Probably, but I've never tested it.

Comment: @schlebe The message shown to you along with the review suspension was supposed to explain that. Unfortunately, we have a very strict character limit there, so we can't write out a very long explanation. If it's not clear to you where you went wrong just from reading the message, coming to Meta is usually the best option.

Comment: @CodeGray (gnat). Just for your information, I can read the last changed question but I cannot see 1. timeline 2. all comments (last comment are not visible) 3. original question not edited 4. vote distribution (number of down and up votes).

Comment: @CodyGray `review suspensions double each time`, so after 64, the next suspension will be (64x2) 128 days? Then the next suspension wil be (128x2) 256 days?